# incompatible declaration in built in function malloc and incompatible types in assignment error in c

Tags: c

```
 char 
 char* c[30];
    c = (char*) malloc(30*sizeof(char) );
```

How does this give an incompatible declaration in built in function warning and and incompatible types in assignment error in the line where i have declared malloc . According to the syntax of malloc , i shouldnt have any error

Comment: Basically a dupe of several of your other questions.

Comment: my warnings still continue even though i heed to all the advices and answers given here thats why i keep posting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `c` as an array. You can't change the value of an array, and an array is not a pointer.

`c` has the type `(char*)[30]`(i.e. an array of 30 char pointers) , not `char*` as your cast suggests.

If you're trying to create a dynamically allocated char "array" for 30 chars, use

```
char *c = malloc(30);
```

If you really want an array of 30 char pointers, and e.g. allocate space for 30 chars in each of its elements, use

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof c/sizeof c[0]; i++) {
  c[i] = malloc(30);
  if(c[i] == NULL) {
    //handle error
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this example not is a good practice to learn. you need (char*) = to know reference Class and malloc + sizeof from Class. sorry your answer it not convince me

Comment: @delive There is no class in C, and no you should not have a cast in there - it is considered bad practice. and you do not need sizeof for a char.

Answer (score 1):

you have to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 0):

`c` is an array of pointers.  Then you're trying to assign a single pointer to the entire array.

Try

```
char *c = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
```

Or if you really need 30 elements, each pointing to a `malloc`ed array of 30 characters, you'll have to make a loop.

```
#define CHUNKSIZE 30
int i;
char *c[CHUNKSIZE];
for (i = 0; i < CHUNKSIZE; i++)
{
    c[i] = malloc(CHUNKSIZE * sizeof(char));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
char* c;
c = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

What you were declaring is an array of 30 char pointers. That's why you were getting incompatible declaration on the `malloc` sentence.

You could have done this though:

```
c[0] = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char) );
c[1] = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char) );
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof (char)` per definition is always 1, so you don't need to write it.

In C `malloc` returns a `void *` so the typecast is unnecessary (even harmful as it suppress useful warnings, don't forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` or `#include <memory.h>`).

```
char* c[30];
```

declares an array of 30 `char *`, probably not what you had in mind.

If you wanted an array of 30 `char` you should have declared

```
char c[30];
```

and forget about the malloc.

If you wanted a pointer on a `char` array which happens to have a length of 30, then you should have written:

```
char *c;
c = malloc(30);
```